# Write Html as Html instead of string in a javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*If you have a better title, change it, but I didn't really knew what wrote instead...*

I would like to know if there is a way to change this kind of ugly thing:

```
jQuery('<div id="loginScreen">' +
            '<h3>Login</h3>' +
            '<div id="logsContainer">' +
            '<div class="leftLoginBox">Login</div>' +
            '<div class="rightLoginBox"><input name="login" class="inputForm" type="text" value="Seby"></div>' +
            '<div class="leftLoginBox">Password</div>' +
            '<div class="rightLoginBox"><input name="password" class="inputForm" type="password" value="123456789"></div>' +
            '<div style="clear: both;"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="checkbox"><input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1"><label for="check1">Remember me </label></div>' +
            '<div id="tryLogUser" class="buttonLogin">Login</div>' +
            '<div class="buttonLogin">Register</div>' +
            '<div class="textAddLogin">Forgot login or password?</div>' +
            '').appendTo('body');
```

in pure HTML, with syntax colors, indentation and everything. Some kind of separator inside the javascript file that does some magic. I know I saw that kind of things with PHP once, but it's server side.

I don't have too much hope, but asking anyway!

Edit: I forgot to say that I want to do that inside a .js file, not a .html file.
(And, actually, inside a .ts file, but it's like .js if you don't know TypeScript).

Edit 2: My situation is particular, I'm building a video game, I can't load too much files dynamically. I was more looking for a trick or workaround. Looks like it's not possible except using hidden div that countains the snippets, but it's not really better...

Comment: Create html elements dynamically and give them the desired classes.

Comment: I can't do both (text/template and creating dynamically) because I'm running inside a file that will be loaded using requirejs, but your solution could be applied on simple scripts inside a basic html document, I'm in pure javascript file. (.js)

Comment: Or you can just put the whole loginScreen div in the body tag and make the div visible or invisible using javascript depending on some event.

Comment: I have learned the hardest way - dont try to pack HTMLs inside javascript.  But instead use "javascript" way in creating HTMLS.  What I usually do is like this: `$('<div>').appendTo(document.body)` instead.  Maybe you will have better luck.

Comment: This might give some insight on approaching the logic for your scenario to code : http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no magic method for being able to write plain HTML into a javascript variable.  It must follow the rules for javascript strings which requires the type of thing you are doing now.

You have three main choices here:

1. For a large amount of HTML, you could create a separate template file and load that dynamically into a JS variable where you can then use the HTML as desired.
2. For smaller pieces of HTML you could include the HTML into a hidden section of your main HTML file and either just use the HTML objects from that or fetch the `.innerHTML` from it with your JS.
3. You can code the HTML into JS strings as you are doing already.

For lots of different HTML snippets, you can put them into a single template file, load that template file, load it into an HTML fragment and then use DOM operations to fetch any single snippet as desired.

Comment: I'm actually building a video game. So, there is a large amount of files. I understand your solution but I don't see how apply it properly. That would means that in the file that build the interface my jQuery() call would reference things existing in antoher file, a kind of template. Complicated, because that means I would need to write all the Html code in one or several files, referenced in the .js usig classes/id... And I also need to import them, hide the content, copy the content used by jQuery and so on. Not the easy way, isn't?

Comment: @Vadorequest - you have three choices: 1) code the HTML into javascript strings, 2) Put the sections of HTML into your main HTML file in hidden sections or 3) Load the HTML dynamically from one or more external files.  Pick the option that makes the most sense for your particular situation.

Comment: 3) Load from external would load too much little file and slow down the game. 2) This solution would create many files and dependencies because they need to be loaded synchronously to be available when the DOM is ready. Too complicated to do and understand. 1) I guess I'm stuck with what I do now. I'll take a look to TypeScript, maybe a workaround exists with it.

Comment: @Vadorequest - Every snippet doesn't have to be in a separate file.  You could put them all in one file, load that file into an HTML fragment and then fetch pieces of it when needed.

Comment: of course, but still, it's a video game, there would be a lot of files, even grouping them. And still dependencies to take care of.

Comment: @Vadorequest - why wouldn't something like the login HTML from your question just be included in a hidden section of your page so you can just make it visible as desired?  Also, if using external files, there don't have to be a lot of files.  You can put multiple snippets in one file and only have one file if you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I'll do that, because it add complexity. But at least I know what choices I have now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mytext = '<div id="loginScreen">' +
            '<h3>Login</h3>' +
            '<div id="logsContainer">' +
            '<div class="leftLoginBox">Login</div>' +
            '<div class="rightLoginBox"><input name="login" class="inputForm" type="text" value="Seby"></div>' +
            '<div class="leftLoginBox">Password</div>' +
            '<div class="rightLoginBox"><input name="password" class="inputForm" type="password" value="123456789"></div>' +
            '<div style="clear: both;"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="checkbox"><input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1"><label for="check1">Remember me </label></div>' +
            '<div id="tryLogUser" class="buttonLogin">Login</div>' +
            '<div class="buttonLogin">Register</div>' +
            '<div class="textAddLogin">Forgot login or password?</div>';

$('.somedivclass').append(mytext);
```

you can simply use an append() function from jQuery

Answer (score -2):

What you want to do is called [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)

Edit

If you need to preload large amounts of data and files use a library like preloadjs http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS

Comment: Honnestly, if that would have been that easy I wouldn't asked.

Comment: Life is hard, deal with it. Just kidding. If you want to have syntax highlight there has nothing to do with js types. You should use templates with syntax support

Comment: I actually have syntax highlight with my IDE. I was more looking for the indention and easy debug.

Comment: You can not blame the whole ECMAscript design only because it does not fit your needs about simple and insignificant quirks about syntax highlights

Comment: I don't blame it. I'm just trying to make the code looking better.

Comment: then use external templates and a preload library, you can split chunks with stages and other pieces and load by demmand